# How can I get response headers from a Handler type?

Tags: go

Given a middleware function with a signature like:

```
func Middleware(handler http.Handler) http.Handler
```

How can I get response headers set and passed to it from a calling function?

First a HandlerFunc (the "base" or main server function) is initialized with some response headers. Then it is passed to and wrapped by the middleware function in the conventional manner.

How can I get the Response and its headers from the `handler` parameter?

I've tried a number of things but can't get at the header values.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, you cannot. In priniple, the `http.Handler` is a *function* that is invoked for each request. As such, it is not bound to any specific request; it will be re-used for an arbitrary number of requests. As such, there is no way to retrieve HTTP request or response headers from an existing `http.Handler` object.

You can however, decorate the handler with *your own middleware* to access HTTP response headers that were set by the middleware function.

A middleware function as described in your question will typically be implemented like this:

```
func Middleware(originalHandler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        // call the original handler that is wrapped by this middleware
        originalHandler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
    }
}
```

This function "decorates" the original `http.Handler` that is passed as a parameter into the middleware function by returning a *new* handler that implements custom logic and calls the original (wrapped) handler function at some point.

Within the new function, you can access the `http.ResponseWriter` object as usual to access the HTTP headers that were already set by the decorated handlers:

```
func Middleware(originalHandler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        // Add new headers to the response...
        rw.Header().Set("X-My-Own-Header", "foo")

        // ...or access data from the original request
        fmt.Println(req.Header().Get("X-My-Request-Header")

        // call the original handler that is wrapped by this middleware
        originalHandler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)

        // Access headers in the response object
        rw.Header().Get("X-Header-Set-By-Middleware")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been assured there's a way to get the original response (and headers) from the wrapped handler, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: @SexxLuthor, as I said, the handler itself is not associated with a request in any kind (if you have a look at the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler), you'll see that the `http.Handler` interface does not offer much besides the `ServeHTTP` method). The idea that I wanted to express in my answer was that you can wrap the handler yourself and then access the original request in your own middleware *before* invoking the wrapped handler function.

Comment: "access the HTTP headers that were already set by the decorated handlers" is actually what I'm trying to do, i.e., get the response headers that were set by `originalHandler`, and then do stuff with them in Middleware(), setting additional header(s) on the original response, before finally calling ServeHTTP. Middleware() decorates the original `http.Handler` now, which returns a new `HandlerFunc` as you describe above.

Comment: You need to decorate the ResponseWriter - https://justinas.org/writing-http-middleware-in-go/